# virtual sound card in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, sound-card

I have to test a piece of software. This software is capable of recording some sound. For my testing it no problem if this sound is silence.
I want to run this software in a docker container running on a virtual server in Azure. The problem is that the virtual servers in Azure do not have a sound card.. 
So the docker containers do not have a sound card either. Now when I start the recording option in the software that I test, i get an error since no sound card is found.

Is it possible to install a fake (or virtual) sound card, so my Virtual Ubuntu system thinks a sound card is available and I can record silence?

Is Jack software the right software for this? Any other (better / easier) options?. (As far as I can see, Jack is not easy :-).. )